# Fast way to populate a big R matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm trying populate a big matrix from smaller matrices.

Let's say I have 2 matrices:

```
set.seed(1)
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(100*20),nrow=100,ncol=20)
rownames(mat1) <- paste("R1",1:100,sep=".")
colnames(mat1) <- paste("F1",1:20,sep=".")

mat2 <- matrix(rnorm(200*10),nrow=200,ncol=10)
rownames(mat2) <- paste("R2",1:200,sep=".")
colnames(mat2) <- paste("F2",1:10,sep=".")
```

The big matrix I need to create will hold the combination of all rows in `mat1` and `mat2`, and its number of columns will be `ncol(mat1)+ncol(mat2)`:

```
combined.rownames <- expand.grid(rownames(mat1),rownames(mat2))

big.mat <- matrix(NA,nrow=nrow(mat1)*nrow(mat2),ncol=ncol(mat1)+ncol(mat2))
rownames(big.mat) <- paste(combined.rownames$Var1,combined.rownames$Var2,sep="_")
```

`mat1` will populate all rows in `big.mat` which correspond to it in columns `1:ncol(mat1)`:

```
idx1 <- match(combined.rownames$Var1,rownames(mat1))
big.mat[,1:ncol(mat1)] <- mat1[idx1,]
```

and `mat2` will populate all rows in `big.mat` which correspond to it in columns `(ncol(mat1)+1):(ncol(mat1)+ncol(mat2))`:

```
idx2 <- match(combined.rownames$Var2,rownames(mat2))
big.mat[,(ncol(mat1)+1):(ncol(mat1)+ncol(mat2))] <- mat2[idx2,]
```

In reality I have a list of matrices: `mat1`, `mat2`, ...,`matn` and their dimensions are higher than in this example.

My question is whether there's a faster/more efficient way to populate `big.mat`?

Note that my matrices are not sparse.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is inefficient to use row names as index.

```
ind <- expand.grid(1:nrow(mat1), 1:nrow(mat2))
big.mat2 <- cbind(mat1[ind[,1],], mat2[ind[,2],])
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be clearer whether I understood this question if the question had used some smaller matrices and specified a "correct answer", but I *think* this an effort to re-invent the "Kronecker product". If I'm correct then with a smaller example it's just;

```
mat1 <- matrix(1:20,nrow=4,ncol=5)
rownames(mat1) <- paste("R1",1:4,sep=".")
colnames(mat1) <- paste("F1",1:5,sep=".")
mat2 <- matrix(1:6,nrow=2,ncol=3)
rownames(mat2) <- paste("R2",1:2,sep=".")
colnames(mat2) <- paste("F2",1:3,sep=".")

 big <- kronecker(mat1, mat2)
 rownames(big) <- combined.rownames
 rownames(big) <- paste(combined.rownames$Var1, combined.rownames$Var2,sep="_")

 > big
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
R1.1_R2.1    1    3    5    5   15   25    9   27   45    13    39    65
R1.2_R2.1    2    4    6   10   20   30   18   36   54    26    52    78
R1.3_R2.1    2    6   10    6   18   30   10   30   50    14    42    70
R1.4_R2.1    4    8   12   12   24   36   20   40   60    28    56    84
R1.1_R2.2    3    9   15    7   21   35   11   33   55    15    45    75
R1.2_R2.2    6   12   18   14   28   42   22   44   66    30    60    90
R1.3_R2.2    4   12   20    8   24   40   12   36   60    16    48    80
R1.4_R2.2    8   16   24   16   32   48   24   48   72    32    64    96
          [,13] [,14] [,15]
R1.1_R2.1    17    51    85
R1.2_R2.1    34    68   102
R1.3_R2.1    18    54    90
R1.4_R2.1    36    72   108
R1.1_R2.2    19    57    95
R1.2_R2.2    38    76   114
R1.3_R2.2    20    60   100
R1.4_R2.2    40    80   120
```

Still have some puzzle about whether this is really the answer since the number of columns is the product rather than the sum of the number of cols. Note that `kronecker` uses `*` as the combination function but another function could be used as long as it is "vectorized".